# Edge warping on BIQU Magician

Tags: print-quality

Whenever I print something on my BIQU Magician 3D printer, there is often edge warping. What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: You should post the bed and hot end temperatures, the speed at which you print, the type of filament used, if any bed adhesive is used. Other factors which you think might be relevant should also be posted.

Comment: Hi Eric welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Note this is a very common (adhesion) problem which has been asked before. Do note that you give too less information to work with.Photos are always welcome!

Comment: Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading "<" and trailing ">" afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.

Comment: Do the edges of all prints (regardless of where they're placed) warp, or do prints warp more on the edges of the actual print surface? The first has been discussed extensively here, the latter might indicate a calibration error.